# What are some drawbacks of this new political system?

Tags: politics, government

I am constructing a world with a new political system.

Evidently, representative democracies of today are far from perfect. The main issues I see are:-

1. The majority of voters lacking interest and education on how to choose the most appropriate candidates, even for their own interests. This leads them to vote based on instinct or habit and not analysis.
2. Lack of choice in candidates, inefficacy of "against all" voting and great difficulty in running for office yourself which forces a voter to vote for "the better of two bad choices".
3. The great potency of money in brainwashing the general public( by spreading misinformation, buying media houses etc. )which is easy to access by a politician who works in the interests of the rich after being elected.
4. The agreement of several parts of government (like different houses) required for drastic change, which is often rare. Although useful to prevent one person doing too much damage, it also slows down the rate at which a good leader can bring about positive change. Gun control is a prime example of this.
5. The division of powers not being effective enough with the judiciary not being as independent or powerful as the executive/legislature. For example, heads of states commonly appoint judges matching their ideology.
6. General politics(not just elections) usually focussed around very few people, such as the president and his main election rival which leads to extremely high levels of fame and publicity to them. This ultimately reduces opposition by common people because they tend to assume that "millions of people" are with that person. This effect helps a leader become autocratic.
7. Weak constitutions which enable the rise of autocratic leaders.

I have been reading about various forms of government, and I feel that a mix of [sortition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition) and [noocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noocracy) would solve most of the above issues. The key principles would be:-

1. An initial jury which will be composed of humans of very high moral standard and intelligence. Some people may argue that quarrels can break out even amongst them, but in my personal experience, the kinder and more intelligent a person gets, the better he /she is able to able to control his/her ego and think critically together for making the world a better place. Often, it is not hard for a group of good people to get along well in the long term and more harm is done when power is concentrated in the hands of a single, bad person. This jury will be given high levels of power in certain areas but very little in others(see point 3). The jury will operate for a moderate period of time(e.g.10 years). A spokesperson will be chosen(not part of the jury and without any power), whose sole job would be to present the decisions of the jury to the public in an appealing manner. The spokesperson will change much more frequently, for example every 2 years. Also, the jury will not be given exacerbated levels of fame and that will remain with the spokesperson.
2. The selection of future juries will be done in two parts. The first being a test of a candidate's knowledge on basic requirements to become a juror. The test will not be competitive and a book will be published which any literate person can read and prepare for. From the candidates who qualify, a small and reasonable number will be chosen by lottery who will then proceed to the next stage of the selection process. The second part will be an internship period where the current jurors will be able to work with the candidates and get to know their competence in administration as well as their morality. Each juror will then select a suitable candidate to replace him/her. This is much better than a short interview where it is difficult to assess someone's personality.
3. A constitution where it is impossible to make changes to laws where it is extremely probable that no future changes will be required. This will include obvious laws like gender and racial equality but also areas pertaining to the structure of the government. Examples could be not allowing a juror to become a spokesperson either before, during or after he/she is part of the jury, term lengths of the juror etc. However, in other areas (like choosing high-ranking officials in the judiciary, executive, army etc. and making laws in non-restricted areas) , the jury will be given higher levels of power than politicians have in the present day in the sense that the agreement of multiple houses will not be required and the majority vote of the jury will decide the laws being made.

Ignoring the feasibility of bringing about this system in the real world, what are possible downsides of this system and is it possible to solve them by making certain modifications to this model?

P.S: I feel that the slight broadness of this question doesn't mean that it gives leeway to opinionated answers because the ideas involved here have been used in some modified form either in the past or present. History and knowledge of a spectrum of political ideas can certainly be used to give some basis.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take rid of the wall of text, it makes the post unreadable. That said, I am afraid you are asking an inherently opinion based and open ended question, as per our [help]

Comment: @L.Dutch edited

Comment: I have to admit, I'm a little confused by the connection between the two parts of this question. You seem to object to electoral dysfunction, lack of separation of powers, and autocracy, but then you propose a unelected aristocracy with power "equivalent to a dictator" over the rest of the government?

Comment: @Cadence It is not an aristocracy in the conventional sense, the selection process is different.

Comment: @Boson For about two weeks, until the aristocracy fixes that....

Comment: "it is impossible to make changes to laws where it is extremely probable that no future changes will be required" Read *The Forever War by Joe Haldeman* societies change and so do morals. Each culture is in time convinced they have found the ethics that will be true forever. Fixing such laws forever will only result in totalitarianism.

Comment: Whenever you try to make a rule (law, constitution, etc) you should not only think about the potential benefits, but also on: 1.) how can this rule be abused? (and what would an abuse be?) and 2.) how can i enforce the rules?
Also, i tend to think that stating your intentions with every rule would help both those who try to follow or enforce the rules, and those who try to come up with an improvement.

Comment: Your criticisms of democracy can largely be addressed by: (1) improving the education system, (2) making it easier to run for office and not using first-past-the-post (which isn't an integral part of democracy), (3) improving the education system and implementing measures against misinformation. (4) Don't have the mess that is the US political system. Also, gun control doesn't happen because of republicans (politicians and citizens alike) and lobbying (ban lobbying). (5) Just change how judges are appointed. (6) \*Shrug\*. (7) Don't have a single person in charge who rules everything.

Comment: "All genders are equal" is fine, but that's not really where the issue would be. Is abortion about gender equality? How about paternal responsibility? What if people simply say "all genders are equal, but these genders don't exist"? The lines get blurry, and we may have gotten some things wrong in the present. And people could easily avoid a problem by claiming that whatever they're proposing doesn't create a gender inequality, or perhaps that a gender inequality is unavoidable and just. Also, we may think something should be set in stone while being very, very wrong about that.

Comment: "Knowledge" tests have historically been used to disenfranchise voters the powers that be don't want voting. Whoever issues the test, or defines what "high moral standards" means (everybody has a different idea of that) effectively selects the jury that selects the government. This system would be an effective way for a totalitarian government to stay in power forever.

Comment: If you're looking for a study on democratic shortcomings, then you've asked on the wrong site. I have no clue how to answer this in the context of worldbuilding.

Comment: `An initial jury which will be composed of humans of very high moral standard and intelligence` and who defines the metrics for those?

Comment: Capitalism, socialism, various types of democracy and Plato's idea of a perfect city and system of government all looked beautifully well planned and borderline perfect at first glance...and then we tried some of those out of the vacuum devoid of power hungry/greedy/lazy/unempathic people they were inevitably created in. Many problems present in the systems we did test out were not only due to unforeseen flaws, but rather people acting o on their selfish interests, usually through actions against the law, such as abusing their positions of power in favor of a friend or family member.

Comment: There's a saying in the military that also applies here: "every strategy is perfect until the first shot is fired", aka it's nearly impossible to make a perfect system or strategy, because we're not a hive mind that values the overall benefit of our species over any individual's selfish interests (because even in societies with a queen, protecting her means protecting the entire colony). It takes half a dozen slips for a source of corruption to settle in a system, and this can be particularly easy to happen in dictatorships and regimes with a small number of super powerful leaders.

Answer (score 10):

### Totalitarian tyranny within years

Whatever political bent the initial jury has will intensify immediately. By manipulating the test and loading it with ideological questions, the jury pool is stacked. The current jury has sole discretion to pick judges, so it's legal.

On the offchance that the jury is close to politically balanced, you'll have future jurors selected for their lack of morals and performance in bed, and bribes.

The instant a few jurors are impeached, the jury will turn into Survivor, and you'll have a purely self interested dictatorship by the end of it. Manipulative psychos will thrive, while honest but dislikable people will be weeded out.

Basically, this system

1. Ignores the fallibility of human nature (stupid, selfish and horny),
2. the need for ambition to check ambition,
3. and meaningful checks and balances.
4. It ignores the instinct towards tribalism (racial, religious and political) and
5. The adage that power corrupts.
6. It's got loads of single points of failure that allow its constitution to be subverted by hard power.
7. It's also elitist as hell and ensures that the stupid will be taken advantage of by their more intelligent countrymen.
8. It ignores that the majority of the world doesn't like racial and gender equality, and even in the part that does, it's riven with debates about what degree of equality to enforce (basic political and civil rights protected, vs equality of opportunity, vs equality of outcome, vs 'right past discrimination with future discrimination so things average out over time').

I'm not American, but I would take up arms and water the tree of liberty if someone tried to make this happen in real life.

PS: Americans have almost never been as wealthy or highly educated as they are now; they built a great country with a population that really was poor and uneducated. The current wealthy, educated population is squandering what their less educated but much harder working ancestors built.  Nor is using instinct a bad thing.

Comment: Have you considered how different juries will interact? The Water&Sewage jury allows a company to rip up one road while the Phone&New jury allows another company to rip up another road, and suddenly the Justice jury finds that the Prison Administration jury has no (accessible) jails left. Do the inmates go free?

Comment: @o.m. I think there's just one big Politburo in this dystopia.

Comment: The OP specified distinct juries. You might assume that one jury overshadows the others (budget? exam preparation? anti-corruption?) but it could also be gridlock.

Comment: @SeanOConnor I disagree with your answer on several points:-

Comment: The system doesn't ignore the fallability of human nature, as mentioned there is a selection process and it is not completely "by lottery" as you seem to assume and only very good people are chosen, if you think that >99% of people are "stupid, selfish and horny"(remember a juror has a choice of dozens of ppl) then that is your pessimistic viewpoint . Its certainly not elitist, the first part of the selection process is a basic test which is non-competitive and the second part is based on your morality, neither of which is elitist. Also, your last paragraph is irrelevant to the question

Comment: @Boson It does ignore human nature. You've assumed there is a class of people that will be consistently smart, moral and sexually disciplined for a decade, even as they exercise absolute power. It absolutely is elitist, you've designed it so only intelligent (educated, actually, to make it worse) people wield power. And the last paragraph directly refutes your underlying criticism of current systems.

Comment: As I mentioned the test is not rigorous with the major part of learning in the internship, and a book with basic knowledge of administration being the sole criteria of the initial test. This is basic knowledge essential which should be a must for anyone in power, regardless of their educational background and also the availability of the book makes it widely accessible. Being "literate" is not elitist.

Comment: Also, if you feel term lengths are a problem then that can easily be modified, as I mentioned I was looking for "modifications" to the model too.

Comment: The power is not "absolute", that is an assumption you have made. To avoid a very lengthy question, I did not include all the checks and balances in the system(which could have been part of your answer).

Comment: Finally, the last paragraph has nothing to do with the criticisms I mentioned. It doesn't directly address anyone of them and you make claims without evidence in it

Comment: @Boson: "The main issues I see are:-

The majority of voters being poor, undereducated, lacking interest and education to choose the most appropriate candidates, even for their own interests". And I say: the history shows that lack of education and being poor didn't stop the USA in the past.

Comment: @Boson You referred to the jury having powers like that of a dictator, before you edited it away. It cannot be 'it doesn't have absolute power' nonsense. when it appoints every senior official in the country *including the judiciary and the military*.

Comment: Finally, anyone who pulls out the 'the voters are too dumb to know their own interests because they haven't got formal education' *is* elitist. They know their own interests, you just don't like their values.

Comment: you are confusing the meaning of "education". It doesn't refer to a person's formal education but rather how educated he is in current political matters.

Comment: The power certainly isn't absolute, it is only slightly more than what is held by current political leaders, in the sense that a majority isn't required of multiple houses. Also, even in present day democracies, judges and military leaders are chosen by elected officials. It isn't a huge difference to the present day. Finally, the question was edited very early on, you should have modified your answer according to that.

Comment: Also, you should be careful in quoting other people. I didn't say "every" senior official and I didn't mention "formal" education anywhere in my question. "dictator" was removed very early on.

Comment: @Boson No. I'm not obliged to change my answer every time you realise you articulated yourself poorly. People answer questions as they're presented. And dictator revealed your intent at that time. Good day. Best of luck coming up with something that has meaningful checks and balances instead of a random mishmash of contradictory progressive tropes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137337/discussion-between-boson-and-sean-oconnor).

Answer (score 5):

This reads like a reaction against the **current US system.** The US gave itself a constitution two and a half centuries ago, in a time before radio and even the general franchise, and patched it ever since. The US constitution was so good that they didn't need a *total* overhaul yet, but the limitations of successive patches are becoming obvious. As to your counter-proposal:

- Will different juries work at cross purposes? The transportation jury wants to build a road through an endangered wetland, the environmental jury wants to protect it, the tourism jury wants the road and scenic rest stops, but no truck traffic ...
- Both intelligence/education and morals are highly subjective judgements. For morals that is obvious, but would you allow somebody onto the education administration jury who isn't qualified as a teacher? Somebody who isn't qualified as a lawyer? Someone who isn't qualified as a statistician? Can you find anybody who qualifies on all three accounts, or which one do you relax?
  Also consider this little flap about an airline testing [South-African-ness](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-61804803).
- There is also the quip by Pratchett that the (fictional counterpart of the) Chinese did select administrators for nightsoil disposal for their ability to write elegant poems about nightsoil. That worked with nightsoil administrators, after a fashion, but it became a problem when it came to gun founders. Which of course obscures the stark necessity to have competent lawyers on all juries, whatever their purpose.
- The Romans tried [adoptive succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerva%E2%80%93Antonine_dynasty#Five_Good_Emperors). Better than [barracks emperors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barracks_emperor), but not good by any objective standard.

Since we are on Worldbuilding, the site for building consistent **fictional** worlds, all those problems mean you should go with it! Adventure is someone else in deep s##t, preferably long ago or far away. I'm reminded of *Cyteen* by C.J. Cherryh.

Answer (score 5):

> An initial jury which will be composed of humans of very high moral standard and intelligence.

You seem to be assuming that high moral standard and intelligence will ensure proper choices. That's a wrong assumption. When I was in high school my math teacher, talking about the guy with the highest grades in our class said:"that he has the highest grades doesn't mean I would entrust him with keeping my wallet".

If that is not enough, here are two more examples of how fallacious is that assumption:

- during my PhD it happened that the supply guy forgot to lock the door of the vending machine. Within minutes it was raided of even those snacks which would have been normally purchased as last desperate purchase when nothing else was available. The building was packed with PhD and PhD students.
- the company where I work employs thousands of masters and PhD: it's a monthly occurrence that somebody in the parking lot hits a car and goes away without leaving a note for settling the damage.

Morale of the story: moral standards are only the facade of what somebody lets other see in public, and high education doesn't ensure nothing more than proficiency in a given topic. There are plenty of stories that show this with factual evidence.

So, the system you are designing is not a perfect system to ensure democracy, but it will make for some interesting story points.

Comment: I might projecting based on my experience here, but if there is any correlation between "kind" and "intelligent", I wouldn't expect it to have a positive sign... There might be understandable reasons, too: someone who is a outlier in any mental trait may find it harder to relate to other people and therefore less likely to be "naturally" kind and empathetic, even while being a morally good person.

Answer (score 5):

The system you describe is an oligarchy (leadership of a small group). The oligarchy "will not be given exacerbated levels of fame", which means they are a shadow cabal ruling with no public oversight and no transparency. Their ability to choose by themselves who becomes a member allows them to commit to group think and ensure ideological homogeneity.

From a worldbuilding perspective, this system allows great storytelling potential. The intrigues, scandals and subterfuge within this shadow cabal could lead to some really interesting plots. For example:

- The story about a group of juror interns trying to get nominated for succession. They try to earn the attention and goodwill of jurors by any means possible. The nice ones will try through hard work and by sucking up to jurors to convince them of their "high moral standards" (i.e. pay lip service to the individual political ideologies of the jurors). The more ruthless ones will sabotage the efforts of their peers to make them look incompetent, or dig up / invent dirt about them to make the jurors question their moral integrity. The bravest ones might even try to blackmail the jurors themselves.
- The protagonist is a political activist with a noble political cause. They try to get the attention of a juror for their idea, but find that they are shielded off by an impenetrable government apparatus that decides who the jurors meet and what the jurors hear. That apparatus was put in place by the jurors themselves.
- Juror A suddenly dies under suspicious circumstances. A testament shows up, which nominates the son of Juror B as their successor. (How did their son pass the lottery? A combination of luck and perhaps the fact that the nephew of Juror B is the government official who oversees the lottery). Some jurors claim that the nomination is legitimate, others that the nomination of Juror B is a fabrication / made under duress. The protagonist investigates, but soon finds himself targeted by assassination attempts themselves.
- Juror A has a dark secret which puts their "very high moral standards" (as the current group consensus dictates) into question. Juror B blackmails them into nominating people loyal to Juror B for important positions in the military, in preparation of a military coup to make Juror B the dictator. Can the protagonist stop Juror B's evil plan, or did Juror B already consolidate too much power to be stopped?
- Journalist starts to investigate the private life of jurors. The jurors, wanting to maintain their seclusion, are not happy. The journalist ends up assassinated. What did they stumble upon? Does the protagonist have the guts to investigate?
- The protagonist is a young and enthusiastic juror. The first law they make and get passed gets read by the spokesperson, and suddenly says something completely different. The protagonist tries to fight it, but thereby put their life in danger. They have to recognize that in the jury of equals, some people are more equal.

So conclusion: An interesting world to write stories about, but not a very good world to live in.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the other answers that explain why your system is brittle to corruption, elitism and descent into tyranny, I think you might be somewhat off the mark as to what a government *does*.

The "job" of a government is not to make correct decisions (for a circular value of correct, usually) in the domain of national management. A government exists as long as it's not overthrown; therefore, a government exists to prevent the population from revolting. One framework to understand this, known as the [Social Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_contract), says that living in a society means agreeing to being bound to certain rules and duties in exchange for having an infrastructure that applies those rules and duties to others, too. This is only acceptable as long as we collectively agree that those who apply these rules are doing to *legitimately* - we willingly relinquish part of our liberty to them, after all. Enough people disagree that the government has the right to rule, and you get a revolt and a change of government.

In history, rulers have used different types of legitimacy - brute force, economic power, divine rights, tradition/inheritance, tribalism, etc. Given the history and evolution of our political thinking, many of these would not really be seen as acceptable today (this is not to say that they're no longer applicable or effective). One of the strengths of democracy is that, in our Western societies, people still feel that it is legitimate - because the voting process gives the sense (illusion?) of choice, of being able to replace an unsatisfactory ruler, and of "representation" (something like a value-based tribalism).

Would the population find your ruling elite legitimate? Some people might, I suppose - this was very much a line (if not the only or even main one) used by many monarchies, where the idea was that heirs could be trained since birth in the art of statecraft in order to make the wisest and most appropriate decisions. But all those monarchies *really* relied on force, applied through a relatively small network of nobles who would be granted the right to land (and therefore the wealth that can be extracted from it) in exchange for military support. What power does your government have to impose its decisions? "Being clever" doesn't cut it, even if you could prove that your elite *does* make wise and optimal decisions.

Apologies in advance to any sociologists or pol sci people for this extremely superficial outline of centuries of their discipline, edits more than welcome.

Comment: Yes this is I think the biggest problem with the proposed system. The spokesperson system makes it even worse. The intention is probably that the spokesperson does all the baby-kissing and gives all the speeches while the technocrats work in peace at fixing whatever needs to be fixed. But the public will figure out that the spokesperson is just a figurehead and the real power lies with some shadowy faceless council - this is a recipe for a revolution as soon there is any kind of serious crisis.

Answer (score 4):

**Steps Missing.**

> An initial jury which will be composed of humans of very high moral standard and intelligence.

Your idea is to only allow politicians that pass some *objective* test of intelligence and morality. This gives extra power to whoever decides what is on that test.

Now you need another system on top of the first system to decide what is on the test. Perhaps the test could be decided democratically. But it sounds like a nightmare voting on an entire syllabus, compared to simply selecting one person from a list.

> . . . where it is impossible to make changes to laws where it is extremely probable that no future changes will be required.

This is circular. It is impossible to change laws that don't need to be changed. Who determines "no future changes will be required"?

Again there is a second system on top of the first system.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what the other answers point out, there is I think a logistical problem with the selection of new jury members. You propose that the jury rules for 10 years. This is about 3652 days. Let's say that one day is enough for the internship of a prospective jury member (even though it's a very short period for such an important decision). This means a jury member will only be able to evaluate 3652 candidates for his replacement. I don't know how many people are in the jury in total, but there can't be that many, since they need to reach consensus before making a decision. So, multiply 3652 by the number of jury members. It's a fairly sizeable but not a huge number.

Now let's say the jury rules over a nation of 30 million - not the smallest but not the largest sized country. You'll see that only a small fraction of the population will have a chance to become jury members. This wouldn't be a problem if there were some aptitude tests to filter out those who are obviously unsuitable to but there aren't any - the selection is purely random.

So if the intention is for the best and brightest to rule the nation, this won't work that well. Most of the people who would've made the best jurors will never get the chance.

Comment: "This wouldn't be a problem if there were some aptitude tests to filter out those who are obviously unsuitable" ... except that such aptitude tests would in and of themselves be a problem, because some group of people (with biases and political goals) would create such tests. But then that's very similar to the problem with the jury idea as a whole, as per [Sean OConnor's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/231830/38314).

Comment: In the system as described, there actually is an aptitude test (designed to ensure a candidate understands their job on the "jury", though as @NotThatGuy points out, that's a very abusable criterion) before the random selection. However that's still a very low bar given that you're randomly selecting no more than a tiny fraction of candidates.